# preventing altered input value checkbox

Tags: php

I have a form with multiple checkboxes that can be selected. If a user wanted they could go in and change the value in the checkbox. I want to know if there is a way I can not accept the form or display an error if the value submitted was not one of the original choices displayed. Here is my code:

HTML Code:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1">
</td>  
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2">
</td>
   <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3">
</td>
   <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4">
</td>
      <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="5">
</td>
      <td>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="6">
      </td>

</tr>



</table>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) { 
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) { 
        echo $check; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Are the choices stored somewhere? I.e. like a database?

Comment: set an array of original choices, initialize it, then compare it to the values that was submitted

Comment: Check for the specific values in your PHP code (and in a form onsubmit event). `if ( $check == 1 || $check == 2 ...`. There are more elegant ways to do that depending on where you get your list of values from.

Comment: @Darren No. They are are just plain HTML. Would it be best store in a database and echo it from there?

Comment: @kevinabelita Could you give me an example of how that would look? I don't quite understand what you mean by initializing an array.

Comment: sidenote: input tags are void elements, `</input>` is unnecessary

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I plan on having 20+ checkboxes and it seems like that wouldn't be the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: Check if the values are between 1 and 6 and if they are Integers that should be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, since html is static (which I dont know why), you could initialize some original values, then compare it. Consider this example:

```
<?php
$original_values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $submitted_values = $_POST['checkbox'];
    foreach($submitted_values as $value) {
        if(!in_array($value, $original_values)) {
            // this particular submitted value does not belong to the original values that is set
            echo 'not good';
            exit;
        }
    }

    // all good if it goes down here
    echo 'all good';
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($original_values as $value): ?>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></td>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

> Note: To test, try to change the values thru the browser [most likely F12], change the dom values. Example: Try to change a checkbox value attribute to 7 or 100, check it the submit.

Also another way:

```
$original_values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $submitted_values = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $differences = array_diff($submitted_values, $original_values);
    if(count($differences) > 0) {
        echo 'not good';
        exit;
    }
    // all good if it goes down here
    echo 'all good';
}
```

Print all the values inside a table:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $submitted_values = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $count = count($submitted_values);
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan='$count'>Values</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($submitted_values as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}
```

Comment: Here is a line from your answer: "if(!in_array($value, $original_values)) "  How would I store something inside of "$original_values"?

Comment: @user3718799 what happens is that, `$original_values` will be compared to the ones that the user submitted on the form.

Comment: I used your code above but now I have ran into a problem trying to display the submitted checkboxes on another page. I tried using this so that all of the values of the selected checkboxes will be displayed on one table instead of having a new table for each value. This code here causes hundreds of tables to be created and they never stop. I guess it is because the while loop forever returns to be 'true'

Comment: while ($submitted_values = $_POST['checkbox']) { ?>          
       
<table>
<thead>
<th>Numbers</th>
</thead>
<tr>
<td><?php foreach($submitted_values as $value) {
        if(in_array($value, $original_values)) { echo $value;}} ?> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php  } } ?>

Comment: `while($submitted_values)`? of course this will run forever.

Comment: What else could I put there instead? I want each $submitted_value to be echoed on one single table and not a table for each $submitted_value.

Answer (score 1):

Store values in a separate PHP file, checkbox_values.php:

```
<?php

$checkbox_values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

?>
```

And your form, another PHP file, main.php:

```
<?php

require 'checkbox_values.php';

?>

<form method="POST" action="checkbox_process.php">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>

<?php foreach ( $checkbox_values as $check ) { ?>

            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $check; ?>" /></td>

<?php } ?>

        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And checkbox_process.php:

```
<?php

require 'checkbox_values.php';

if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) { 
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) { 
        if ( in_array($check, $checkbox_values) ) { echo $check; } 
    } 
}

?>
```